# Unable to execute Javascript from Wicket renderHead method second time

Tags: javascript, wicket

I am working on converting date components (fromDate and toDate) to [Bootstrap Date component](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). In order to do that I have created a text field in wicket and then executed a script on that text field to generate the required output. However, I am getting only the first text field converted to date component and second one is not as the script was not executed on it. Please see image and code below

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<span wicket:id="rangeDateValue" style="width:400px">
    <span class="input">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input wicket:id="fromDateValue" class="std" />
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="input">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input wicket:id="toDateValue" class="std" />
        </div>
    </span>
</span>
```

**Java**

```
public DateRangePicker(final MarkupContainer parent, String id, IModel<RangeDateModel> model)
    {
        super(id, model);
        this.startDateTime = addValueDatePickerNew(this, "fromDateValue", new PropertyModel<String>(model, "fromDate"));
        this.endDateTime = addValueDatePickerNew(this, "toDateValue", new PropertyModel<String>(model, "toDate"));
        this.add(new DateTimeRangeValidator());
        parent.add(this);
    }

private TextField<String> addValueDatePickerNew(final MarkupContainer parent, final String id, final IModel<String> model)
{
    final TextField<String> result = new TextField<String>(id, model) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) 
        {
            String jsDateField = "jQuery(function () {"
                    + "var idDate = jQuery(\"input[name*='dateValue' i]\").attr('id');\n"
                    + "console.log(\"idDate: \"+idDate);\n"
                    + "var calIcon = \"<span class='input-group-addon dateTimePick'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span></span>\";"
                    + "var idDateValField = jQuery('#' +idDate);\n"
                    + "idDateValField.datetimepicker({\n"
                    + "useCurrent: false,\n"
                    + "collapse: true\n"
                    + "});\n"
                    + "idDateValField.after(calIcon);\n"
                    + "idDateValField.next('span.input-group-addon').click(function(e) {\n"
                    + "idDateValField.focus();\n" 
                    + "});\n"
                    + "});";
            response.renderOnDomReadyJavaScript(jsDateField);
        }
    };
    result.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    parent.add(result);
    return result;
}
```

I am getting console statement only for "fromDate" and not "toDate". As both are in the same DOM and execution of script happens after DOM Ready, I am assuming its applying only for "fromDate" and unable to get the right way to do it.

Comment: Check the jquery selector you are using to get the idDate. You are selecting two input tag, but .attr('id') returns only the id of the first selected tag.

Comment: Yes, good catch @Andrea Del Bene. I have replaced id finding code with 
` var idDateValField = jQuery('#" + uniqueId + "');\n ` where _uniqueId _ is created from UUID. It is coming to `var idDateValField = jQuery('#8a948a245c5fbada015c5fc54d210015');` and this time `idDateValField.datetimepicker(..)` still not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to "inject" markup id into javascript code:

```
 String jsDateField = "jQuery(function () {"
                    + "var idDate = '" + getMarkupId() +"';\n"
                    + "console.log(\"idDate: \"+idDate);\n"
                    + "var calIcon = \"<span class='input-group-addon dateTimePick'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span></span>\";"
                    + "var idDateValField = jQuery('#' +idDate);\n"
                    + "idDateValField.datetimepicker({\n"
                    + "useCurrent: false,\n"
                    + "collapse: true\n"
                    + "});\n"
                    + "idDateValField.after(calIcon);\n"
                    + "idDateValField.next('span.input-group-addon').click(function(e) {\n"
                    + "idDateValField.focus();\n" 
                    + "});\n"
                    + "});";
            response.renderOnDomReadyJavaScript(jsDateField);
```

Comment: Awesome. This is more cleaner solution than adding my way of creating unique id through UUID. Thq @Andrea Del Bene